# Python - How would I print every key of a dictionary that has a value named "x"?

Tags: python, dictionary

Example:

```
dict = {1: "X", 2: "Y", 3: "X"}
```

I want to print every key that has the value "X".

Desired Output:

```
1 3
```

Edit:
Yeah, yeah, whatever. I worded it wrong when I searched for the question - it is probably a duplicate from what I've seen but I came up with a solution after all your... helpful comments.

```
item = (input("\nItem Name: ")).lower()
if item in recipes.values():
    print("\n--------------------[Recipes]----------------------")
    for key, value in recipes.items():
        if value == item:
            print(key)
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The terminology for dictionaries are pairs of `key:value` , you're wanting to ask how to print every key that has the value `"X"`

Comment: @RoryDaulton I have no idea where to start, and Google can't tell me anything.

Comment: @DavyM Heh... Fixed :) thx

Comment: You want to start with `for`. [Iterating over dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops).

Comment: I just googled that... Maybe your keywords are off

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in dict.items():
if value == 'X':
    return key
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing dictionaries keys and values. 
Notice that in a dictionary

```
dict = {key1: value1, key2: value2...}
dict[key1] = value 1
```

you can use dict.keys() to iterate over the keys of the dictionary.
you shuld try somthing like

```
for key in dict.keys():
    if dict[key] == 'X':
        print key
```